# Documenting who a function is called by

Tags: coding-style

Is it bad style to use a comment above a function to document who calls a function?

As an example:

```
# Called by foo
def bar(something):
    return something+1
```

It strikes me as bad practice, but I would like to check myself before going around telling others not to do it.

Comment: This shouldnt be a question on SO, first. SO discourages discussion oriented questions. And to answer it, it really depends on individual's perciption. Sounds perfectly fine to me, to comment a function like this, and infact a good practice, but only if that function is called by a single function

Comment: Your comment may well grow stale over time and become misleading.  See, there's the discussion MohitC warned about :-)

Comment: @MohitC in some languages, nested functions are legal, so if a function is only ever used by one function, it might be better to just nest it instead. But I agree on your first statement, this probably belongs on Programmers or something.

Comment: @user2085282 Thanks, I will submit it over on programmers.

Comment: @user2085282 This question would be downvoted and closed as "primarily opinion-based" on Programmers. Please read: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/22815)**.

Comment: @kjschiroo don't double post, if it gets flagged as such, it will be moved by a mod.

Comment: @Snowman sorry, removed the post. Is there a place in which this question would be appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad style, good style -- too subjective. But there are some obvious pros and cons.

Obvious con: this is something to maintain. If `bar` gets called by something other than `foo`, or `foo` is renamed, or anything like that, the documentation either needs to change or it'll become incredibly confusing*.

<sub>* Naturally this isn't a big deal if you're absolutely sure this won't happen.</sub>

Obvious pro: it shows people the caller of this function. That may or may not be useful info. It may or may not be redundant with the tools you use.

So there you go. Weigh the obvious pro and obvious con, and try to make a good decision.